# Import ORM in django celery task and call ModelName.objects.all()

Tags: django, django-models

In my django app, one of my models has a method that doesn't take any arguments and updates some values. I would like to automate this process on a daily schedule. I was having a look at django-celery with CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE and I made a few tasks to test the out celery but was having trouble using the django ORM in one. for example.

```
from celery import task
from polls.models import Question 

@task()
def updateAllQuestions()
    for question in Question.objects.all():
        question.SomeMethod()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I solved problem. I was having trouble using the normal python interpreter and used the manage.py shell instead, which allowed the import of the ORM properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your import is broken:

```
from polls.models import Question
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that. It was a typo when I put it up. That wasn't what was causing me trouble though.